# Save In-App Video To Camera Roll?

Tags: iphone, video, camera

Is it possible to take a video that is embedded within the app and save it to the camera roll? If so, how? Is it the same UIWriteImage thing?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez the only thing I know how to write to the camera roll is UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum, but that is only for UIImages

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this code assuming you already know how to save an image:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
       //Save the video
       NSURL *movieUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
       UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([movieUrl relativePath], self,@selector(movie:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }
}
```

Or you could try:

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  if([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
    NSURL *movieUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:movieUrl completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"CameraViewController: Error on saving movie : %@ {imagePickerController}", error);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"URL: %@", assetURL);
        }
    }];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For iOS 8 and higher, use the [PHPhotoLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHPhotoLibrary). *ALAssetsLibrary* is deprecated.

Include:

```
@import PhotosUI;
```

And then use this to save your movie:

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^
 {
     [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:<%Your Movie URL%>];
 }
                                  completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error)
 {
     if (success) {
         NSLog(@"Movie saved to camera roll.");
     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"Could not save movie to camera roll. Error: %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Help help help... I tried so many things. This answer seems to be the most elegant, but I'm really not able to make it work on my device.
For the movie URL, I'm passing the UIImagePicker dictionary value : `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` which look like that: `file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A305CE7A-3959-479A-AE61-1BB184C3A679/tmp/83HDFS29__ABAG84H9-AA33-4137-AA2E-BE1JDHFBC41.MOV`
I get this error: `"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)` for the `localizedDescription` of Error object.