# How do I save a video stored in resources to camera roll?

Tags: video, camera, media-player, avfoundation

I am playing a movie using the code below but was wondering whether there was a way to save this movie file that I have saved in the app to the camera roll of a device when a user presses a button.

```
NSString *moviePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.m­p4"];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback­:) 
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotif­ication object:moviePlayer]; 

[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, check out this other question for the answer,

[Save In-App Video To Camera Roll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407401/save-in-app-video-to-camera-roll)

You would use: `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`